# Bootstrap modal not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, servlets, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing a server side program in java which reads a folder and returns all the files which resides in that particular folder. I am able to do it. The file names which I got from server needs to be dynamically add in the bootstrap modal. I am able to do it but all the names of the files are not rendering properly. I have added a screenshot. To call server side java script I am using Ajax call which gets triggered on the page load. Where I am doing the mistake not able to figure out.[image: This is the screenshot of the modal]

HTML Modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="seziureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
     label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Generate Seizure Report</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="seizureFilesLoad"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"/EDAPPGProject/file_list.jsp",
        headers:{
                Accept:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"
            },
        success:function(data){
            $('#seizureFilesLoad').html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("Some Error Occured! Please visit after some time");
        }
});
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code in question.

Comment: Need to see your html code for bootstrap modal first.

Comment: I have added html code also now